# Using libtom/lbtomcrypt in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm very new to use Github libraries and it's not clear to me how to use the **libtom library** (https://github.com/libtom/libtomcrypt) in my Eclipse project. I have read that it is necesary to compile the library and then link that compiled in the project, how should i do that?

The library says that it is modular and that made me think that i only had to paste it into the project to work (I have a couple of libraries that were only necessary to paste them into the project and they worked) but I think this library is not so since it always sends this error:

```
C:\TP_CPP/Src/EncryptFunctions.cpp:73: undefined reference to `rijndael_ecb_decrypt'
```